# R: How to query for date format in output from scan?

Tags: r, list, date, format, character

I have hear a really silly output format from observations which I've to read in with scan.

Here's a snipplet from (data.dat), where I've marked header and data blocks:

```
06.02.2014    # header
PNP         
-0,005 
00:05#587     # values 
00:15#591  
23:50#587  
23:55#587
07.02.2014    # header
PNP
-0,005
00:10#587     # values
00:15#590  
23:55#590  
24:00#593
08.02.2014    # header
PNP
-0,005
00:05#590     # value
00:10#595  
00:15#600  
23:50#600  
23:55#607
```

The problems are:

- I've got date for several years in 5min resolution,
- each day has is own header (constant length), beginning with the date and two additional entries,
- the length of the time series (format HH:MM#value)for each day is not constant, data gaps exists (not shown in the example)

My aim is a data.frame of the form date, time, value.

So, I need a loop or something, which analyses the single list elements (output from  scan(file=data.dat, what=" ") as **character**). Since the time blocks have different lengths, I'd like to subsetting my daily data beginning with the date, skipping some further header elements, and than strsplit the time#value elements of the list, which has been outputted by

```
crap     <- scan(file = data.dat, what=" ")   # import as list
```

the strsplit works well with

```
tmp <- strsplit(crap[4:8], split="#")
df  <- data.frame(date=as.Date(crap[1],format = "%d.%m.%Y"), time=sapply(tmp, "[[", 1), W=sapply(tmp, "[[", 2))
```

However, I've no idea how to analyse the elements from the list (as characters), if they have an valid date format.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution but it may be very specific to the question you asked and what I interpreted.

First read the data and remove the `PNP and -0,005` from the data.

```
crap     <- read.table(file = "data.dat",comment.char = " ")
a        <- as.vector(crap$V1)
a        <- a[-grep("PNP|-0,005",x = a)]
```

Now I extract the dates contained in the vector `a`

```
dateId   <- grep(".",x=a,fixed=T)
uniquedate    <- as.matrix(a[dateId])
> uniquedate
     [,1]        
[1,] "06.02.2014"
[2,] "07.02.2014"
[3,] "08.02.2014"
```

Now I create a vector of dates of same length as no. of values in the dataset by repeating the dates for the number of values present in the corresponding date.

```
len      <- length(dateId)
dateRepVal    <- c(diff(dateId)-1,(length(a) - dateId[len]))
dates     <- unlist(sapply(1:len,FUN = function(x){rep(uniquedate[x],dateRepVal[x])}))
```

All other elements expect the date in our dataset `"a"` are time-value pair.using this information now I get the time and val by using the `strsplit` function and then create the dataframe.

```
timeVal   <- strsplit(a[-dateId],split = "#")
time      <- sapply(timeVal, "[[", 1)
val       <- sapply(timeVal, "[[", 2)
DF        <- data.frame(date = dates,time=time,val=val)
```

The final required output looks like below.

```
>DF
         date  time val
1  06.02.2014 00:05 587
2  06.02.2014 00:15 591
3  06.02.2014 23:50 587
4  06.02.2014 23:55 587
5  07.02.2014 00:10 587
6  07.02.2014 00:15 590
7  07.02.2014 23:55 590
8  07.02.2014 24:00 593
9  08.02.2014 00:05 590
10 08.02.2014 00:10 595
11 08.02.2014 00:15 600
12 08.02.2014 23:50 600
13 08.02.2014 23:55 607
```

Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: I've two edits though. dates      <- unlist(sapply(1:len,FUN = function(x){rep(uniquedate[x],dateRepVal[x])})) #nVal
DF         <- data.frame(date = c(dates),time=time,val=val)

Comment: Glad it helped.